# msb of signal in sytem verilog without using $bits

Tags: system-verilog

```
logic msb
logic [<parametrized bit width>-1:0]long_signal_name

assign msb = long_signal_name[$bits(long_signal_name)-1];
//assign msb = long_signal_name[<parametrized bit width>-1];
```

i have multiple instances of this so wanted to check if there is an easier way than `$bits` or a function.

Thanks

Comment: Explain what you would have wanted using $bits. And use correct syntax.

Comment: What is wrong with the commented out line? that is the standard way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try the `let` construct or a macro.

```
let MSB(sig) = sig[$left(sig)];
assign msb1 = MSB(long_signal_name1);
assign msb2 = MSB(long_signal_name2);
```

You could also try reversing the bits and hope the compiler optimizes this down to a simple expression.

```
assign msb = {<<{long_signal_name}};
```